# I can't get my iPod touch to show up in iTunes what am I doing wrong?

Tags: itunes, windows, ipod-touch

I recently purchased a new iPod touch, when I set it up I used my user on my Mom's Windows 7 laptop (and a Wi-Fi network). But, right now that computer is not the one I am using, I am using a Windows XP computer (and DSL). Anyway, both have iTunes on them so I figured I would have no problem connecting to my home computer.

My iPod shows up on my computer but just as a camera and not under devices in iTunes. When  I tried to run diagnostics, it showed that I had a connection problem between my computer and iPod (well, I pretty much knew that already:). I tried running updates on iTunes but it then it said that I wasn't connected to the internet.

So, let me see if I can pull this all together! What is going wrong when I try to connect my 5th generation iPod touch to iTunes on a Windows XP computer?

Comment: Oh and, it _is_ charging while plugged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at Apple's forums, I discovered that others who had a similar problem had not recently updated their iTunes. So, after doing a bit of poking around I discovered my iTunes hadn't been updated in quite sometime!

I accessed the administrator account on my computer, clicked on the "Start" button (the button in the lower left corner in XP and 7), there I found an Apple software update button, clicked on that and it brought iTunes up to date. I disconnected my iPod and then reconnected. This time using iTunes version 11.2.2.3. Now everything is connected and is working just fine (although iTunes now looks much different and requires some getting used to!)!